# Could not load assembly

Tags: c#, .net

I have a normal winforms app. I run it and it calls some logic in another .dll (another project part of the solution). I get an error (my own exception) saying could not load assembly etc etc.

I've used the assembly log viewer but could not find an issue - all I found was that the windows service the program uses was installed/deployed on another account. My winforms app calls this service, which in turn calls logic in its own and different .dlls.

Could this be an issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you use a FileDialog and open/save/write a file to another directory other than the one that contains your exe/dlls, it will change the programs working directory if you do not set the `FileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true`.  This one caused me fits for a while, and would explain why it appears intermittent.

Comment: This is the most likely cause of an "intermittent" failure.  Of course, looking for DLLs in the working directory is a bad idea to begin with.

Comment: How/where do I set that value?

Comment: RestoreDirectory is a property of FileDialogs.  For example, if you are using an OpenFileDialog called ofd, just set ofd.RestoreDirectory = true.  The would apply for a SaveFileDialog as well.

Comment: I don't use that. Just call various classes etc.

Answer (score 0):

Check your project **.NET Framework** version, and your assembly **.NET Framework** version, problem could be there.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the assembly it's looking for is in the same directory that you're running the application from, or that it's registered in the GAC (Global Assembly Cache) - and that it's the correct version.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your application and all its dependencies are either all 32 bit or all 64 bit assemblies.

Comment: How do I do that? This problem is intermittent btw.

Comment: @blade33: Bitness isn't intermittent, so this is probably not the problem in your case.  Run `dumpbin /headers` and `dumpbin /clrheader` on a .DLL or .EXE to find out the platform.

Comment: You can also check the configuration manager in Visual Studios, which is where you would fix it if it is wrong (and then recompile).

Comment: By intermittent, do you mean that it sometimes successfully loads the problem assembly (if so I agree with Ben, bitness is not the problem), or is it possible you your application only sometimes tries to load the promblem assembly?